# Passing data between between screens in react-native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to pass the same data between three screens in react-native,the data works on the first screen and when passed to the second screen it works but it does not work on the third screen

the code below was used to pass the data to the second screen

```js
this.props.navigation.dispatch(
    CommonActions.navigate({
      name: 'Second screen',
      params: {
        username: username,
      },
    })
  );
```

In the second screen, this is used to pass the data to the third screen:

```js
<Button
    title="Add Contact"
    onPress={() =>
      this.props.navigation.navigate('AddContact', {
        user: this.props.route.params.username,
      })
    }
  />
```

And I used the data in the third screen as shown below:

```js
this.props.route.params.user
```

Is there a way for doing this

Comment: That strange, could you please try to use a consistent variant `navigation.dispatch(
  CommonActions.navigate({
    name: SCREEN_NAME,
    params,
  }),
);`

  or
  
`navigation.navigate(SCREEN_NAME, params);`

on both screens

Comment: You've got `.username` and `.user`, is it on purpose?

Comment: @konstantin Yess